# how to add a custom function to a class that differs per object?

Tags: python

```
class Item(object):
  def __init__(self, quantity, name, description, effect): #effect is in code and used by the computer, not shown to the player.
    self.quantity=quantity
    self.name=name
    self.description=description
    self.effect=effect
def useitem(Item):
  if Item.quantity>0:
    Item.quantity-=1
    Item.effect
```

I'm trying to make it so that a certain function will be triggered when an `Item` is used, but I haven't a clue on how I'm supposed to do it. I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
  bandaid=Item(1, "band-aid", "helps with cuts", health+=20)
```

but, of course, that doesn't work. 
How can I do this?

My coding knowledge is extremely limited, so it would be great if you could please explain what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Read the docs about `lambda`. Moreover you can also use functions (without `()`) as parameters because they are objects like everything else in Python.

Comment: Just a note to improve readability: before and after operators (e.g. `-=`) there should be a single space. [See the PEP 8 guide on spaces here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, quantity, name, description, effect): 
        self.name=name
        self.description=description
        self.effect= 'self.' + effect

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
        self.inventory = {}
    def get_item(self, item):
        if item in self.inventory:
            self.inventory[item] += 1
        else: self.inventory[item] = 1
    def use_item(self, item):
        if self.inventory[item] and self.inventory[item] > 0:
            self.inventory[item]-=1
            exec(item.effect)

p1 = Player()
bandaid=Item(1, "band-aid", "helps with cuts", 'health += 20')
p1.get_item(bandaid)
p1.use_item(bandaid)
print(p1.health)
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost. How does this allow me to add 20 to `health`? And also, if I put that under the `useitem` function, how can I change it so that, say, a medkit would add 50 to `health` instead?

Comment: Well most likely you would have another class such as `PlayerCharacter` that would have a `health` attribute, and that class would actually have methods such as `acquire_item` and `use item`.  We could then go on to implement these methods.
To have a different effect take place you would just initialize the object with a different argument in the `effect ` parameter.

Comment: I made the function `Item.useitem` and under it is the same code as the `use(self)` in the post. However when I ran it `health` did not change(it was at 10 and stayed at 10 after using it.) Could you explain how the effect would act on the variable `health` as a string?